# How to connect Pivot Points H/L with a line in TradingView Pine?

Tags: pine-script

I found script for pivot H/L looks like this:

[image]

But I want that the H and L are connected with a line, like this:

[image]

And here is script:

```
study(title="Pivot Points H/L", shorttitle="Pivots H/L", overlay=true)
len = input(14, minval=1, title="Length")
    //The length defines how many periods a high or low must hold to be a "relevant pivot"

h = highest(len)
    //The highest high over the length
h1 = dev(h, len) ? na : h
    //h1 is a pivot of h if it holds for the full length
hpivot = fixnan(h1)
    //creates a series which is equal to the last pivot

l = lowest(len)
l1 = dev(l, len) ? na : l
lpivot = fixnan(l1)
    //repeated for lows

plot(hpivot, color=blue, linewidth=2, offset= -len+1)
plot(lpivot, color=purple, linewidth=2, offset= -len+1)
//plot(h1, color=black, style=circles, linewidth=4, offset= -len+1)
//plot(l1, color=black, style=circles, linewidth=4, offset= -len+1)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Blaz, welcome to SO! Please make sure to provide code of what you have already tried and remember that SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: DId you ever find a solution for this?  I'm trying to do the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Without going deep into code, you can produce your second picture with pine code.

You should record highs in one variable, and record signal that pivot is active in another. When pivot active code triggers you can plot with offset.

Lets say you are searching for pivot in price with 2 right candles lower value.
After 2 candles you will get signal that 2 candles before, you had your pivot and then you should execute something like this:

```
plot(is_pivoth ? pivot_high_price : na, location=location.absolute, offset=-2)
```

Comment: Did you actually try this?

Comment: Yes, during making of one script, I was trying to do same, just not on price bar, but on another indicator. Logic is same.

Here is example of script I found on TV, maybe it can be useful for thread starter:
https://www.tradingview.com/script/EvxrInX6/

Answer (score 0):

> But i will like that the H and L will be connected with this line.

It's unfortunately at this time not possible to code trend lines in TradingView Pine.

A TradingView representative said [here](https://getsatisfaction.com/tradingview/topics/using-pinescript-to-draw-a-trendline-or-annotate-text) in February 2017 that making trend lines with scripts is on the roadmap. But he didn't say when that feature is possible. So it might be a while, or it might become available next month.

---

As a work around you can plot a line with the `plot()` function. That, unfortunately, has the disadvantage that the line appears over each bar and cannot be 'turned off'.

(I see from your code that you already used `plot()` earlier, so I think this is something you already tried and didn't find a good solution.)

Comment: tnx for answer.

Comment: ...the reason is that pine-script are not using single variable values, but every value is a semi-infinite *series* (each representing one tick). So a "1" is actually the series: `(1,1,1,...)`.